# How to stop method that is running in java after 60 seconds

Tags: java

I am currently attempting to learn how to stop a method that is running in Java after 60 seconds and have come up with the following code:

```
`long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 long end = start + 60000L;
 while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
     Experiment.runToStringArrayListExperiment();
 }`
```

With this code, I believe the Experiment method should stop running after 60 seconds, however, it does not do this. I don't know if I am just missing something or if there is an oversight on my part, which is likely the case. If you notice what is wrong or have a different way of doing this, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The condition for the loop will not be re-examined unless control returns from `Experiment.runToStringArrayListExperiment()` - If this code were to be replaced with a simple sleep, then it works as advertised

Comment: I believe you would need to place this mechanism directly within the method being run or call this mechanism from within the method so as to continue polling for how long it has been running. This mind you would most likely only be beneficial for loop code the contains the risk of running indefinitely which you should be avoiding when coding anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Executor with a timout set to 60 seconds:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
   public Object call() {
      return something.blockingMethod();
   }
};

Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);

try {
   Object result = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
   // handle the timeout
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // handle the interrupts
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
   // handle other exceptions
} finally {
   future.cancel(true);
}
```